# Scan the string and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me with the logic in SQL.

Scan the country codes (each 3 Byte) in source string (15 byte fixed width) and look for aNy of the below values, If found concatenate found values with a colon (:) in between

IND, US, AUS

If any of these values are found, then

**If Country code is 'IND' set to 'INDIA' Else
If Country code is 'AUS' set to 'AUSTRALIA' Else
If Country code is 'US ' set to 'UNITED STATES'
Else None of above value MATCHES Then move Blank**

Example: If the source string contains:

'INDUS AUSNZ CAN' Then results should be 'INDIA:UNITED STATES:AUSTRALIA'

Comment: Can you show us how much have you tried so far ?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense - how does `AUSNZ` equate to UNITED STATES and `CAN` equate to AUSTRALIA? There's no "US" in your sample data unless you count the US in both INDUS and AUSNZ - in which case which is it....

Comment: Each country is fixed width 3 BYTE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fastest or best solution, but should work with CASE. Obviously this is only doable with a few attributes:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN country LIKE '%IND%' AND country LIKE '%US%' AND country LIKE '%AUS%' THEN 'INDIA:UNITED STATES:AUSTRALIA'
    WHEN country LIKE '%IND%' AND country LIKE '%AUS%' THEN 'INDIA:AUSTRALIA'
    WHEN country LIKE '%IND%' AND country LIKE '%US%' THEN 'INDIA:UNITED STATES'
    WHEN country LIKE '%US%' AND country LIKE '%AUS%' THEN 'UNITED STATES:AUSTRALIA'
    WHEN country LIKE '%IND%' THEN 'INDIA'
    WHEN country LIKE '%US%' THEN 'UNITED STATES'
    WHEN country LIKE '%AUS%' THEN 'AUSTRALIA'
    ELSE NULL
  END country_new
FROM table
```